# How do I use PHPMailer? I can't find a simple decent tutorial online

Tags: php, email, mime, phpmailer

I'm trying to send out a Plain/HTML multipart email out and I'm currently using PHP's mail() function. Many people have recommended PHPMailer so I thought I'd give it a go.

However, as everything seems to be nowadays, it appears very complicated. I downloaded it and it talks about installing it and configuring MySQL connections and SMTP connections!? All I want to do is use a nice class that will build the MIME emails for me and send them! I understand the SMTP possibilities but it all seems so complex!

Is there some way of simply just using it, for example, include a php file (no server installation or re-compiling PHP!) and then just using the class to build and send the email?

I'd be very grateful if someone could explain things simply! I'm sure it's possible and I can't believe after my hours of searching there's no really good, simple article about it online. Everything's TOO complicated when I know it doesn't need to be!

Comment: Did you try reading the readme provided with [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)? It contains a straightforward example of sending an HTML email exactly as you describe. I know this is an old question, but it lacks even a basic link to PHPMailer itself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [SwiftMailer](http://www.swiftmailer.org) instead.

Comment: Thanks, I got this working perfectly first time! Great docs too! :-)

Comment: May I ask why you do such recommendation? I too think phpmailer isn't the best nowadays, but I'm kind of uninformed. Thanks

Comment: a single line, link only answer? THIS IS NOT AN ANSWER. It doesn't even touch on OP's question.

Answer (score 8):

Pretty way (from [this link](http://www.evaragroup.com/mailer/docs/extending.html)), first extend PHPMailer and set the defaults for your site :

```
require("class.phpmailer.php");

class my_phpmailer extends phpmailer {
    // Set default variables for all new objects
    var $From     = "from@example.com";
    var $FromName = "Mailer";
    var $Host     = "smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com";
    var $Mailer   = "smtp";                         // Alternative to IsSMTP()
    var $WordWrap = 75;

    // Replace the default error_handler
    function error_handler($msg) {
        print("My Site Error");
        print("Description:");
        printf("%s", $msg);
        exit;
    }

    // Create an additional function
    function do_something($something) {
        // Place your new code here
    }
}
```

Then include the above script where needed (in this example it is named `mail.inc.php`) and use your newly created `my_phpmailer` class somewhere on your site:

```
require("mail.inc.php");//or the name of the first script

// Instantiate your new class
$mail = new my_phpmailer;

// Now you only need to add the necessary stuff
$mail->AddAddress("josh@example.com", "Josh Adams");
$mail->Subject = "Here is the subject";
$mail->Body    = "This is the message body";
$mail->AddAttachment("c:/temp/11-10-00.zip", "new_name.zip");  // optional name

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "There was an error sending the message";
   exit;
}

echo "Message was sent successfully";
```

Comment: Why in PHP use a lot of extension, which tightly couples class and introduces dependencies, why not use aggregation instead?

Comment: much appreciated for actually answering OP's question and providing code. this worked for me - thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know anything about PHPMailer, but I recommend using [Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html). Here's a simple example with an attachment:

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setBodyText('This is the text of the mail.');
$mail->createAttachment($myImage,
                        'image/gif',
                        Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE,
                        Zend_Mime::ENCODING_8BIT);
$mail->setFrom('somebody@example.com', 'Some Sender');
$mail->addTo('somebody_else@example.com', 'Some Recipient');
$mail->setSubject('TestSubject');
$mail->send();
```

It probably does everything you want (Attachments, HTML, SMTP-Configuration, ...). By default it uses `sendmail`, like the `mail()` function, so you don't have to configure anything like SMTP if you don't need it.

It also has very good documentation, so you won't have trouble finding examples.

Comment: How do I extract the necessary functions from Zend framework?